# Which UdpClient with SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress actually accepts data?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, udpclient

I need to receive data on a specific endpoint address. But when I respond to a request, I need to send the data from the same endpoint the data was received on (otherwise the other party ignores it).

The thing is that I don't want to process requests sequentially, so one thread only receives data to pass it to another thread that processes it and sends a response. AFAIK, the same UdpClient instance can't be used concurrently, so the only idea I came up with was to create a new instance each time I want to send a response to the sender.

To achieve what I want, I create the client the following way (**SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress**):

```
var udpClient = new UdpClient
{
    Client = CreateBoundUdpSocket()
};

public static Socket CreateBoundUdpSocket()
{
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    socket.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, optionValue: false);

    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1010));
    return socket;
}
```

The thing is that the UDP clients used for responding are created only for that single operation, and disposed right away then. How can I be sure that only the first created instance will accept data, not the other ones? I don't want to lose any packets.

According to the tests I performed, only the first instance receives anything. Even when I set its receive buffer to 0, no other instance gets any data. Only when I close the first instance, does the next one created get the data. It looks as if the creation order was important because whenever I close the instance that currently receives data, the next created one starts getting it (not a random one, but the next one).

Long story short, can I be sure that only the first instance I create will be receiving data?

**-- EDIT --**

To clarify my general approach (maybe incorrect):

```
var server = new UdpClient { Client = CreateBoundUdpSocket() };

while (true)
{
    IPEndPoint sender = null;
    var data = server.Receive(ref sender);

    Task.Factory.StartNew
    (
        (object param) =>
        {
            // [process the request]
            var request = (Tuple<IPEndPoint, byte[]>)param;

            // and send a response
            using (var client = new UdpClient { Client = CreateBoundUdpSocket() })
            {
                var someResponse = new byte[] { };
                client.Send(someResponse, someResponse.Length, request.Item1);
            }
        },
        state: new Tuple<IPEndPoint, byte[]>(sender, data)
    );
}
```

Comment: You should have a master (client) server (slave) relationship.  The server should not respond unless it is sent a command unless the server is broadcasting.  So you shouldn't miss any messages if  the server waits for a command from client before sending a message.

Comment: The thing is that I have no control over that. I just need to create a server which processes requests as quickly as possible. The requests come from different and completely independent clients. I want to serve each independently, and that's why I create separate threads for processing incoming requests so that the server only cares about receiving the incoming data, without blocking.

Comment: You do not understand my response.  You are saying same thing I said.  The request is the command from client to server and the response is the message from server to client.  Now is the client code posted on the Server or on the Client.  You have a UdpClient on the server (the listener) and a UdpClient on the Client machine.  The term Client can mean at application layer Client/Server and at the connections layer a socket.  The listener on server should always stay open.  Every time a client connects the Asynchronous Accept method get a new socket and the server responds on the socket.

Comment: To clarify my approach, I added an example code that presents the general idea of how the request processing works. The server socket and client socket are opened by the same process, as you can see. I'm not sure what you mean by the Accept method. I attempted to use it, but it seems impossible on a UDP socket, doesn't it? AFAIK this would be possible on a TCP/IP socket, am I wrong?

Comment: Look at the msdn socket example for asynchronous server.  The AcceptCallback method.  The handler is the socket (client).  Then ReadCallback get the same socket.  So you can return the response on the same socket after extracting the message.  No need to create a new client (socket).

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, and this would be perfect. However, this is not supported on a UDP socket. Here's the example you probably had in mind: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Comment: There is no difference in the TCP or UDP for AcceptCallBack and ReadCallback.  UdpClient, UdpListener, TcpClient, and TcpListener all inherit the same socket.  The only time it will not work if you are using UDP Broadcast.  Broadcast you do not have a connection.

Comment: OK, but when I attempt to listen on a SocketType.Dgram / ProtocolType.Udp socket, I'm getting an exception saying that the operation is not supported on this kind of socket. When I change it to SocketType.Stream / ProtocolType.Tcp, it works.

Comment: Reuseaddress should only be used on a Listener.  It only works if the address is already in use.  Udp apparently uses Receive instead of listen.  code looks the same.  See example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: That's true, reuse is set on the listener. But because I need to send a response from the same endpoint the request was received on, I bind the responding socket as well, even though I'm not listening on it.

Comment: So can't you bind in the AcceptCallBack?  The Server listens on a main socket for the port number.  Then every time a new client connects it create a new socket while continues to listen on main socket.  The new socket is passed to the Accept method.  The socket is capable of receiving data and sending data.  If you are going to bind once for each client then it is done in the Accept.  If you are going to bind for each receive message then is is done in the ReadCallBack.

Comment: Talk is cheap, can you show me the code, please? :) IMHO this is impossible to do, but maybe I don't understand something. I'll be grateful. Thank you for devoting your time to this case.

Comment: Use the receive method which doesn't have an accept.  If you need the accept then use TCP.

Comment: I can't use TCP...